# Text of UIButton in UICollectionViewCell gets overwritten. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uicollectionviewcell

I have a UICollectionView, with cells being subclassed from UICollectionViewCell and loaded from nib in the initialization of the subclass. The subclassed cell contains a subclass of UIButton where the text is set to TXT in the interface builder.
For testing purposes, I have done:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    ISOCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:CELL_ID forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.uicellbtn.titleLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", (int)indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

and it can be seen that the sequence of numbers (1-9) show in the cells, but only for a split second until they are replaced with the default text from the interface builder (TXT)!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set the button text you have to use the `setTitle:forState:` method.

```
[cell.uicellbtn setTitle:[NSString stringWithFormat@"%d", (int)indexPath.row] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

This *still* trips me up every now and then.